# Possible mistake in iOS dev guide

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

From [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503):

"... Windows do not have any visible content themselves but provide a basic container for your application’s views. ..."

What does "visible" mean? I can (without adding any UIViews to the window) set the colour of the window and it will be visible (on simulator) using the following two lines:

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

If I run my app, it will be white. Hence the question: what does "visible" mean in this context? And if a UIWindow is not supposed to have any visible content then why is it nonetheless implemented as to have an attribute backgroundColor? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I do have a guess: the attribute backgroundColor might be there for debug purpose and the dev guide might be wanting to say "a UIWindow is not intended to display any content in the form of textures etc., which is done by UIViews..." but this is just a guess and I want to hear other's insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIWindow` is a subclass of `UIView`, which is why you'll see the `backgroundColor` property. I'm not exactly sure how iOS handles this internally, but I assume that your root view controller's `view` property is loaded into the window's view to display content.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, the term "visible content" in the docs means "subviews". The intent is that windows do not provide any subviews, widgets, or any other content. The background color isn't content, it is a property.

Comment: True, this sounds like a viable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Background color is what shows through when you don't have any content.

Comment: That's correct. And if I set it to white, it will show through as "white".